# Batch file not returning correct value after using bat to exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm having lots of issues with this script. It's supposed to read the a file (that the user specifies) then save it to the `storeresult` environment variable.

I'm using a BAT To EXE converter that doesn't affect any batch commands, so it's not that. (Just if you're wondering why i'm calling `storvar` instead of `storvar.bat`)

The main script (`storvar.exe`):

```
set a=%~1
set b=%~2
set c=%~3
for /f "delims=" %%a in (stor\%a%.stor) do set storeresult=%%a
pause
```

The script i'm using to call the script (No errors with calling):

```
storevar Hi hi
pause
echo %storeresult%
pause
```

When I call it, it just returns the result (`%storeresult%`) as nothing, I cant find the issue!

Comment: What is in `stor\Hi.stor`? Where are you writing this file? Please show all your code if you expect an answer.

Comment: Did it work before you used the bat to exe converter?

Comment: No, Fleet Commands answer helped me.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  As you get settled into the community, it might be prudent to devote a few minutes towards reading the Help section tutorials. For example, if it is true that Fleet Command's answer helped you, the following is probably applicable:  [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

When you try to define and use a variable, you must always be mindful of its [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Environment variables that you define using `set` command are only valid within the scope of the process in which they are defined. It is easy to prove with an experiment:

1. Open one Command Prompt and try to define `set a = b`. Use `set` to verify that it is properly defined.
2. Now, open a second Command Prompt and invoke `set`. You see that `a` is not defined in this scope.

`storvar.exe` is a separate process. Hence, it has its own scope. Whatever environment variable you define in it stays there and is deleted when it exits.

**So, is there an alternative?** Well, yes. I myself use PowerShell instead of the deprecated batch files; it can extract stuff from the file and either use them straightaway or emit them to the next script. (Microsoft officially supports compiling PowerShell to EXE, although you can find newbie-oriented ones on TechNet Gallery as well.) AutoIt is another alternative.